# jqgrid in mvc with multiple delete

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

i want to add multiple delete functionality in my Jqgrid with MVC here there is code for my current grid in Action there is two thing View and delete but i want a check box and out side the grid one button when click on it the checked item should be delete and also before delete action fire message for confirmation please help.

$(document).ready(function ()

{

```
    @if (ViewBag.Filters != string.Empty)
    {
        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Filters);
    }

    $("#jq-grid").jqGrid({
        url: '/Home/GetList',//Service URL to fetch data
        datatype: 'json',//Data Type which service will return
        mtype: 'GET', 
        postData://Data that will be posted with every request
        {
            filters: function () {
                return $.toJSON([
                                //Here add the parameters which you like to pass to server
                                { Key: "EmployeeName", Value: $("#txtEmployeeName").val() },
                                { Key: "Id", Value: $("#txtId").val() }
                                ]);
                }
        },
        colNames: ['Employee Id', 'EmployeeName','empPhoto', 'Action'],//Column Names
        colModel: [//Column details
                    { name: "Employee Id", index: "Employee Id", width: "220px" },
                    { name: "Employee Name", index: "EmployeeName", width: "220px" },
                    { name: "empPhoto", index: "empPhoto", width: "50px" ,formatter:imageFormat },
                    //Do not allow sorting on Action Column


                   { name: "Action", index: "Action", sortable: false, width: "220px" }


                  ],

        autowidth: true,//Do not use auto width
        sortname: '@ViewBag.EmployeeGridRequest.sidx',//This will persist sorting column
        sortorder: '@ViewBag.EmployeeGridRequest.sord', // This will persist sorting order
        imgpath: '',//if some images are used then show grid's path
        caption: 'Employee Grid List',//Grid's Caption, you can set it to blank if you do not want this
        scrollOffset: 0,
        rowNum: @ViewBag.EmployeeGridRequest.rows, //Total Pages
        page: @ViewBag.EmployeeGridRequest.page, // Current Page
        rowList: [@ViewBag.EmployeeGridRequest.rowList], // Page Selection Options
       viewrecords: true,
      //  height: "100%",
        altRows: true,//Use alternate row colors
        altclass: 'jqgaltrow',//Alternate row class
        hoverrows: true, //Do not hover rows on mouse over
        pager: $('#jq-grid-pager'),//Div in which pager will be displayed
        toppager: true,

        pgbuttons: true,//Show next/previous buttons
        loadtext:'Loading Data please wait ...',
        //loadui :'block',//enable by default, block will disable inputs, remove this line if you do not want to block UI
        loadComplete: function (response) //Incase you want to perform some action once data is loaded
        {

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach that I took after finding no built in solution that jqgrid api provides. Hope this helps. I took this approach because I wanted to allow deletion of those records that passed business rules and to alert user of those records where problem was found.

```
            #jqGrid delete button
            //Delete selected devices from jqgrid standard checkbox
             jQuery("#jqDevice").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#jqDevicePager', {
                caption: "",
                title: "Delete selected records",
                buttonicon: "ui-icon-trash",
                position: "first",
                onClickButton: function(){

                    //alert("edit button clicked");
                    var selIds = $("#jqDevice").getGridParam("selarrrow");
                    var len = selIds.length;

                    $("#dialogDeleteConfirm").dialog({
                      buttons : {
                        "Confirm" : function() {
                            //loop through each rows selected and delete
                            if(selIds.length > 0){
                                for(var i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) { //traverse the selarrow array in reverse order.
                                    //alert("Deleting Device... " + selIds[i]); //Test
                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        data: "deviceID=" + selIds[i],
                                        url: '/Device/DeleteDeviceByID',
                                        async: false,
                                        success: function(data, textStatus){
                                            //successfully deleted row
                                            $("#jqDevice").delRowData(selIds[i]);
                                            alert("Successfully deleted records...");
                                        },
                                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {      
                                            alert(JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText));                                  
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }else{
                                alert("No rows selected.");
                            }
                            //Close Dialog after user confirms delete action
                            $(this).dialog("close"); 
                        },
                        "Cancel" : function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                      }
                    });                
                }
            });


            # Controller Action
            public ActionResult DeleteDeviceByID(int deviceID) 
            {
                try
                {
                    //update LastModBy before deleting
                    Device device = _deviceRepository.GetDevice(deviceID);
                    device.LastModBy = User.Identity.Name;
                    _deviceRepository.SaveChanges();

                    _deviceRepository.DeleteDevice(deviceID);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //throw new Exception (ex.Message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty));
                    //return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty) });
                    //Good way to raise error in JSON format
                    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                    return Json("There was a problem deleting ID - " + deviceID + " :  " + ex.Message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty) + 
                        "\r\n\r\n Please try again. If the problem continues, please contact ... for further assistance.");

                }

                return Json(new { success = true });
            }
```

Comment: In order to render checkbox on jqgrid you need to property multiselect: true